# Angular show tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I display input form with a textarea and button.
I want to show tooltip when textarea data  is invalid.

When i used then method $setValidity to enable tooltip. It shows well but its style and position are incorrect.

```
$scope.importedTemplate_Form.imported_html.$setValidity('validHtml', false);
```

html:

```
%form#form{'name' => 'importedTemplate_Form', 'novalidate' => 'true', 'ng-submit' => 'saveImportedHTML()'}
    .fieldwrap
      %textarea.form-control{'field-error-tooltip' => 'true', 'name' => 'imported_html', 'error-name' => 'validHtml', type: :text, 'ng-required' => 'true' ,'placeholder' => 'Type or copy your code here', 'ng-model' => 'import', 'ng-change' => 'validateHtml(true)'}
    .pull-right
      %button.btn.btn-arrow.continue{ 'ng-disabled' => 'importedTemplate_Form.$invalid', 'style' => 'margin-left:10px;'}=t 'application.import'
```

Comment: Your code is too complex, please reduce it to the minimum that reproduces the issue

Comment: please create a fiddle or plunkr with a simple example of your problem